# question about normed vector spaces and its subspaces

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

We know that every finite dimensional vector subspace of a normed space $X$ is closed in $X$.

Does the result also holds for infinite dimensional subspaces of $X$ ?

MY answer is not. For instance, we can take $X = C[0,1]$ and $Y = span(f_0,f_1,......)$
where $ f_i = t^i$. But how can I show that $Y$ is not closed in $X$ ???

Comment: Find a non-zero element of $C[0,1]$ with infinitely many zeroes.

Comment: When they say is closed in $X$, do they mean it is a closed subspace? or it is closed wrt operations? this is causing me confusion

Comment: Certainly, closed subspace.

Answer (score 1):

The space $Y$ is just the space of all polynomials. The [Weierstrass theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem#Weierstrass_approximation_theorem) says that $Y$ is dense in $C[0,1]$; that is, $\overline{Y}=C[0,1]$. Since $Y$ is not $C[0,1]$ (you should have no difficulty coming up with a continuous function that is **not** a polynomial), it follows that $Y$ is not closed.